# Best strategy for a game board spinner

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series

Consider the following problem, from Henk Tijms's *Understanding Probability*:

> You spin a game board spinner with $1000$ equal sections numbered as
>   $1,2,\dots,1000$. After your first spin, you have to decide whether to
>   spin the spinner for a second time. Your payoff is the total score of
>   your spins as long as this score does not exceed $1000$; otherwise
>   your payoff is zero. What strategy maximizes the expected value of
>   your payoff?

Call $r_1$ the result of the first spinning. The random variable $r_1$ can take any value from 1 to 1000 with equal probability $p=\frac{1}{1000}$. For the result of the second spinning, $r_2$, the same consideration holds.

Let $m$ be a number from 1 to 1000 so that if $r_1<m$, then we spin the wheel for the second time, otherwise we do not.

The probability that the sum $r_1+r_2$ exceeds 1000 is $\frac{1000-r_1}{1000}$.

The expected value of the payoff is

$$
E_m(X) = \sum_{r_1=1}^m \sum_{r_2=1}^{1000-r_1}(r_1+r_2)\frac{1}{1000^2} + \sum_{r_1=m+1}^{1000}\frac{r_1}{1000}.
$$

I don't know if I have made any mistake so far, but how to find the optimal value for $m$ at this point? Probably I need to sum the sequence and express $E_m(X)$ as a function of $m$, but I have no clue on how to do this.

Edit: the answer by @bram28 is clearly the best way to solve the problem, but in case anybody is interested in the approach with the series, I found with Mathematica that
$$
E_m(X)=\frac{-m^3-3 m^2+3002998 m}{6000000}-\frac{(m-1000) (m+1001)}{2000}.
$$
Then, imposing $\mathrm{d}E_m(X)/\mathrm{d}m=0$ gives
$$
\frac{-3 m^2-6 m+3002998}{6000000}+\frac{-m-1001}{2000}+\frac{1000-m}{2000}=0,
$$
Wich has the solution
$$
m=\frac{1}{3} \left(\sqrt{18018003}-3003\right) \simeq 414
$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can keep the math a little simpler. Yes, there should be a point $m$, above which it is better not to spin again, and below which it is better to spin again.

To find $m$, the expected value of the payoff when spinning for a second time should therefore be the same as not spinning for a second time after first spinning $m$. That is, we find should $m$ such that the first spin gives $m$, and the expected total payoff for spinning a second time is also $m$.

Now, after first spinning $m$, any number from $1$ to $1000-m$ (and of course there are $1000-m$ such numbers) on the second spin will keep you smaller or equal to $1000$. The expected value of such a 'safe' spin is $\frac{1001-m}{2}$, and hence the expected total payoff is $m + \frac{1001-m}{2}$

On the other hand, any number from $1001-m$ to $1000$ (and there are exactly $m$ such numbers) on the second spin will get you a total of over $1000$, and thus get $0$ total points.

So, you have a chance of $\frac{1000-m}{1000}$ of getting a payoff of $m + \frac{1001-m}{2}$, and a chance of $\frac{m}{1000}$ of getting a payoff of $0$

Thus, the expected payoff spinning a second time is:

$$\frac{1000-m}{1000} \cdot (m + \frac{1001-m}{2})$$

So, set that equal to $m$ (the payoff when not spinning a second time), and now you solve a fairly easy quadratic equation for $m$ to that inflection point, above which it is better not to spin, and below which it is better to spin again.

In fact, let's just approximate this number by setting:

$$\frac{1000-m}{1000} \cdot (m + \frac{1000-m}{2}) = m$$

That means:

$$\frac{1000-m}{1000} \cdot (\frac{2m+1000-m}{2}) = m$$

$$\Rightarrow \frac{1000-m}{1000} \cdot (\frac{m+1000}{2}) = m$$

$$\Rightarrow (1000-m)(m+1000) = 2000m$$

$$\Rightarrow 1,000,000 -m^2= 2000m$$

$$\Rightarrow m^2 + 2000m-1,000,000 = 0$$

Solve for $m$:

$$m=\frac{-2000+\sqrt(2000^2+4,000,000)}{2}=\frac{-2000+\sqrt(2000^2+2000^2)}{2}=\frac{-2000+2000\sqrt(2)}{2}= (\sqrt(2)-1)\cdot 1000 \approx 414$$

Finding precise integer $m$:

When $m=414$, the expected payoff is:

$\frac{586}{1000}\cdot (414+\frac{1+586}{2})=0.586 \cdot (414+293.5)=0.586 \cdot 707.5=414.595$

Slightly higher, so yes, spin again!

When $m=415$, the expected payoff is:

$\frac{585}{1000}\cdot (415+\frac{1+585}{2})=0.585 \cdot (415+293)=0.585 \cdot 708=414.18$

Slightly lower, so don't spin again!

OK, so the strategy is: for any first spin $1$ through $414$: spin again, and for any first spin $415$ through $1000$: don't spin again.